# How to align the button at the bottom of the screen on Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to make a form to send messages and I need the title and the recipient's email to be in the upper part, in the middle occupying most of the screen this **EditText** `et_mensaje` and in the lower part of the screen is the **send button**, but in my xml file the button goes out of frame. I do not want to place values at the heights of `et_mensaje` I want it to automatically adjust to the different screens

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
   >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/text1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="@color/NEGRO"
         android:text="Message Demo"
         android:textSize="20dp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:layout_below="@id/text1"
         android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/LinearLayout1"
            android:textColor="@color/NEGRO"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Para: " />

         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/et_email"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="9"
             android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
             android:textSize="16sp"
         />

     </LinearLayout>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="@color/NEGRO"
         android:layout_below="@id/LinearLayout1"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:text="Mensaje:" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/et_mensaje"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:textColor="@color/NEGRO"
         android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
          android:inputType="textPersonName"
          />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bt_SendButton"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_below="@id/et_mensaje"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:text="ENVIAR MAIL" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything you need doesn't fit on the screen, then you can use **ScrollView** so that you can scroll to the bottom of the screen. Since your parent layout is **LinearLayout**, you can have the *Send* button at the very end as you have right now.

If you want everything to be on the screen (without using **ScrollView**), then you can set the *weight* for each component.

(Also, I don't think you'll need the outermost (parent) **LinearLayout**; it seems like you're using **RelativeLayout**.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `android:layout_below="@id/et_mensaje"` from `Button`  and add `android:layout_above="@+id/bt_SendButton"` in `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

you can use weight to make it better instead of giving values

like this

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:weightSum="10"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<EditText
     android:id="@+id/et_mensaje"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:textColor="@color/NEGRO"
     android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
      android:inputType="textPersonName"
      />

<Button
     android:id="@+id/bt_SendButton"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_below="@id/et_mensaje"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:text="ENVIAR MAIL" />
```

and add other element as you want but remember to give 0dp